# Error while creating component with argument constructor

Tags: angular, components

I have a simple `component` like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'error-handler',
  templateUrl: './error-handler.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error-handler.component.css']
})
export class ErrorHandlerComponent  {

  constructor(public error?: any) { }
}
```

and when I go to browser I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ErrorHandlerComponent: (?).
```

I have register my new `component` in module so I don't know why this error occures. I don't call the constructor from anywhere yet.

Comment: remove `public error?: any` from your constructor and put it in the class as a variable.

Comment: @Faisal doesn't help

Comment: then we need more information about your code

Comment: What else do you want?

Comment: create a plunker with minimum error reproducible code. Here is a template link: https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Constructor parameters in a component (or directive, or pipe, or service) will try to get injected by the dependency injector. Change your component to this:

```
@Component({
  //...
})
export class ErrorHandlerComponent  {

  public error: any

  constructor() {}
}
```

<strike>Or use the `@Optional()` decorator:</strike>

```
@Component({
  //...
})
export class ErrorHandlerComponent  {

  public error: any

  constructor(@Optional()public error?: any) {}
}
```

Optional doesn't work when your type is `any`

Comment: I have the same issue and after your changes I still have the same errors

Comment: @Aryjadna based on your code, these are the only solutions. Where the first one is preferable, because you would never be able to inject an `any` like that. My suggestion is that you go look a bit more at the guides provided at https://angular.io. Or make sure your changes I suggested are really processed in your project